# Encrypt integers using AES without encodings

Tags: python, aes, pycrypto

Is there any way to encrypt integers **without** encodings?

i.e. `AES.new(key, mode, iv).encrypt(some_integer_without_encodings)`

... and get the ciphertext directly in integers (without any form of encodings/decodings)?

Comment: I doubt that is possible. You can convert the source integer to string and that will work but AES does not produce integers as output. Its output is binary and needs encoding to make it something you can attach, read, show or post.

Comment: @Hannu Thank you! May I ask what is the "final" form of input it takes in the calculation? Also binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/cipher.html

[image: I/O restrictions for AES]

`bytes` or `bytestring` are the expected I/O data types for AES